# JProgressBar duplicating

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

My JProgressBar is worked perfectly up until i set my JFrame GlassPane visible. It then randomly decides to shoot across the screen and duplicate.

Here is an animated GIF displaying the bug. This happens no matter what my code is - even with an extremely basic GUI

http://i.gyazo.com/bd70df610a3cad6bfff258b80f21c78a.gif

This ONLY happens when i do 
this.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);

Here is the code:

```java
    public void setProgress(final int percent) {
            pb.setValue(percent);

            if (percent == 100) {

                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                    FadingMirror glassPane = new FadingMirror();
                                    instance.setGlassPane(glassPane);

                                    ((FadingMirror)instance.getGlassPane()).startAnimation();
                                    ((FadingMirror)instance.getGlassPane()).setVisible(true);
                            }
                    });
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void addText(String text) {
            System.out.println(text);
    }

    public static class FadingMirror extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

            /**
             *
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 7341931028635559650L;
            private float opacity = 0f;
            private Timer fadeTimer;

            public void startAnimation() {
                    fadeTimer = new javax.swing.Timer(75, this);
                    fadeTimer.setInitialDelay(0);
                    fadeTimer.start();

            }

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    opacity += .03;
                    if(opacity > 1) {
                            opacity = 1;
                            fadeTimer.stop();
                            fadeTimer = null;
                    }
                    repaint();
            }

            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    //super.paintComponent(g); //Cannot do this before setting composite without destroying the animation
                    ((Graphics2D) g).setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, opacity));
                    g.setColor(getBackground());
                    g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
            }
    }
```

}

Thanks for reading

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: You're using a cusomt component for the `glassPane`, which is overriding the `paint` or `paintComponent` methods, but not call it's super method first

Comment: MadProgrammer - Looks like you're absolutely right. Only problem is i'm overriding it because if i call super it screws up my fade animation

Comment: Then it looks like you need to fix your fade animation.

Comment: `Graphics` is a shared resource, you MUST call `super.paintComponent` in order to prepare the `Graphics` for painting, otherwise it will contain what ever was painted to it previously...

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Here you go MadProgrammer - my bad for being vague. http://pastebin.com/2ML3T1kZ

Comment: Make a copy of the Graphics object, set the composite on **that** and draw with that. Then dispose of it.

Comment: Make the component transparent

Comment: *"Here is the code:"* An uncompilable code snippet is not an MCVE or a runnable example, as has now been linked twice for you in the comments.  Try following the link and reading the document..

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels - I tried that. Same result. http://pastebin.com/eA9PNHZa

Comment: MadProgrammer - Worked! I simply set setOpaque(false);

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of the Graphics object, set the composite on **that** and draw with that. Then dispose of it.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); 
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, opacity));
    g2.setColor(getBackground());
    g2.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
    g2.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Don't suppose you could add a vote to [request to fix the hanging close bracket](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831)?

Answer (score 1):

`Graphics` is a shared resource.  Generally, any Swing component painted by the frame uses the same `Graphics` context.  One of the jobs of `paintComponent` is to prepare the `Graphics` context for painting, typically by filling it the current background color.

Because `Graphics` is a shared resource, any changes you make to it will affect any other components that are painted after it.  You should be restoring the `Graphics` context to it's previous state before `paintComponent` exists.  This is most easily achieved by using `Graphics#create` which will create a snap-shot the properties of the `Graphics` context, but won't affect the original.  You should then ensure that you call `Graphics#dispose` on your copy when you're done.

Your glass pane should also be transparent, allowing what ever is below it to be painted.

[image: Fade]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setGlassPane(new FadePane());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class FadePane extends JPanel {

        private float alpha = 0;
        private Timer timer;

        public FadePane() {
            timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    alpha += 0.1f;
                    if (alpha > 1.0) {
                        alpha = 1f;
                        timer.stop();
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(alpha));
            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public void fadeAway() {
            setVisible(true);
            timer.stop();
            alpha = 0f;
            timer.start();
        }

    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(50, 50, 50, 50));

            JButton btn = new JButton("It's better to burn out then fade away");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JRootPane rootPane = (JRootPane) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JRootPane.class, TestPane.this);
                    FadePane fadePane = (FadePane) rootPane.getGlassPane();
                    fadePane.fadeAway();
                }
            });
            add(btn);
        }

    }

}
```